# How to use Rest Framework's default token authentication view?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I am trying to use DRF's builtin [TokenAuthentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) view, but I can't get it to work.

Here is the test:

```
import requests
import json
data = json.dumps({
  'username': 'test-sandbox-root', 
  'password': 'password'
})
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/api/auth', data=data, headers=headers)
>>> r.status_code
400
>>> r.text
'{"non_field_errors":["Unable to log in with provided credentials."]}'
```

But the user clearly exists:

```
>>> User.objects.get(username='test-sandbox-root', password='password')
<User: test-sandbox-root>
```

I've added the **`DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES`** to my settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

And migrated the **`rest_framework.authtoken`** app:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...

    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',

    ...
]
```

And added **`optain_auth_token`** to my **`urls.py`**:

```
from rest_framework.authtoken import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('/api/auth', views.obtain_auth_token),
]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: it is clear that you set password wrong if it is set in database as plain text

Comment: @iklinac Thanks that will probably solve my problem.  I was using a fixture with test user data and a plaintext password.